# ASP.Net's String.Replace behaves differently if run on Windows 7 workstation than on Windows 2008 R2 server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, replace

I have an ASP.Net project using .Net framework 4.0. The following line works fine if my project is published to my Windows 7 workstation:

```
strTemplate = strTemplate.Replace("<span style=\"background-color: yellow;\">", "");
```

However, if I publish the project to a Windows 2008 R2 server, the above replace does not take place. There's no error; the server just doesn't find the pattern and doesn't replace it. Can anyone tell me why, or how to get around this? I've tried putting an "@" in front of my pattern string, but then the string wants to terminate at the double quote before "background-color", whether the backslash is there or not.

Comment: Most likely because `strTemplate` does not contain string you are searching for - so please post sample value of that variable that causes the issues.

Comment: Doubt this is the problem (and only a comment) but I think it will use string comparison of the current culture and they might be different.

Comment: @Alexei - no strTemplate does contain the string I'm searching for. It's matched if the project is running from a Windows 7 machine; it isn't matched if the project is running from a Windows 2008 R2 server

Comment: @Blam - can you elaborate on how I can examine what the current culture is on the server?

Comment: Show some effort.  Search msdn for .NET Current Culture

Comment: @Blam - thanks - I have been searching "current culture", but knowing that this is .Net dependent, not server dependent, is a big help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
strTemplate = strTemplate.Replace(@"<span style=""background-color: yellow;"">", "");
```

You have to put two double quotes when using the `@` notation.

EDIT:
Assuming you have access to running applications on your Windows 2008 R2 server, try running this code there and on your Windows 7 workstation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;

namespace CurrentCulture
{
    public class Info : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public void ShowCurrentCulture()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Culture of {0} in application domain {1}: {2}",
                              Thread.CurrentThread.Name,
                              AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName,
                              CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Info inf = new Info();
            // Set the current culture to Dutch (Netherlands).
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "MainThread";
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            inf.ShowCurrentCulture();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

If the current culture on your Windows 7 workstation is different from your Windows 2008 R2 server, you will need to adjust your Windows 2008 R2 thread's current culture to match what you're expecting.

You can set your thread's culture to a new culture like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-NL");
```

My code is modified from the MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, Cameron, but this does not give me any different result. The search string is still not matched.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include `CurrentCulture` information as suggested by Blam.